# While loop as a function to determine the number of levels given the minimum number of cases of the level in r

Tags: r

```
# Creating a dataframe.
x <- sample( LETTERS[1:4], 1000, replace=TRUE, prob=c(0.1, 0.2, 0.69, 0.01))
y <- sample( LETTERS[6:9], 1000, replace=TRUE, prob=c(0.1, 0.2, 0.68, 0.02))
z <- sample(16500:350000, 1000, replace=TRUE)
df<- data.frame(x, y, z)
```

The categorical variables in my dataset have levels that rarely occur.
Let's say I need to have at least 100 cases in each level whithin a factor which can be done using  `suggest_levels` function. This function determines levels that are similar to each other either in terms of their average value of some quantitative variable or the percentages of each level of a two-level categorical variable.

```
library("regclass")

t <- suggest_levels(z~x,data=df,target=3,recode=TRUE)
df$x <- t$newlevels
table(df$x)
```

As one can see I set "target" option to 3 manually.
To be able to get the perfect number of levels given the minimum number of cases whithin a level I use the following while loop:

```
p <- (length(levels(df$y)) - 1)
k <- min(table(df$y))
f <- c()

while (k < 100) {
    SL_1 <- suggest_levels(df$z ~ df$y, data = df, target = p, recode = TRUE)
    j <- SL_1$newlevels
    p = p - 1
    k <- min(table(j))

    if (k >= 100) {
        f <- append(f, length(unique(SL_1$newlevels)), after = length(f))
    }
}
```

Could there be any function that looks for the number of levels based the desired minimum number of cases whithin the level? For now I've got this, but it doesn't seem to work:

```
foo <- function(colname, number) {

    number <- (length(levels(df[[colname]])) - 1)
    d <- min(table(df[[colname]]))
    num_of_levels <- c()

    while (d < 100) {
        SL_1 <- suggest_levels(df$z ~ df[[colname]], data = df, target = number, 
            recode = TRUE)
        j <- SL_1$newlevels
        number = number - 1
        d <- min(table(j))
        if (d >= 100) {
            num_of_levels <- append(num_of_levels, length(unique(SL_1$newlevels)), after = length(num_of_levels))
        }
        return(num_of_levels)
    }
}
```

I am new in programming, so any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If allowed, I would like to suggest a different approach than yours. As  generally, using loops in R is a "no no".

You try to filter out groups with less than 100 cases. Group is considered as a  case under both x and y variables. To do that I recommend the use of the `tidyverse` approach.

```
df_filter <- df %>% 
  #Grouping under the variables x and Y 
  group_by(x, y) %>%
  #Creating a new variable that counts the number of cases per group. 
  mutate(N = n()) %>% 
  #Filter groups with less than 100 cases. 
  filter(N> 100)
```

Result:

```
summary(df_filter)

 x       y             z                N        
 A:  0   F:  0   Min.   : 17111   Min.   :125.0  
 B:144   G:125   1st Qu.:101317   1st Qu.:144.0  
 C:604   H:623   Median :176031   Median :479.0  
 D:  0   I:  0   Mean   :180700   Mean   :355.4  
                 3rd Qu.:263174   3rd Qu.:479.0  
                 Max.   :349127   Max.   :479.0
```

## Edit, using the `regclass::suggest_levels()` function.

Please note that I am not familiar with the `suggest_levels()` function, so I used your code.

```
require(tidyverse)
require(regclass)
require(magrittr)

#Creating new factor
df$NewFactor <- as.factor(
  suggest_levels(z~x,data=df,target=3,recode=TRUE)$newlevels)

#filter factors with less than 100 cases
df_filter <- df %>% 
  group_by(NewFactor) %>% 
  mutate(N = n()) %>% 
  filter(N > 100) 

summary(df_filter)

 x       y             z          NewFactor       N        
 A: 93   F:111   Min.   : 16553   A:297     Min.   :297.0  
 B:204   G:198   1st Qu.:101965   B:688     1st Qu.:297.0  
 C:688   H:653   Median :183983   C:  0     Median :688.0  
 D:  0   I: 23   Mean   :185751             Mean   :570.1  
                 3rd Qu.:267289             3rd Qu.:688.0  
                 Max.   :349379             Max.   :688.0
```

## Additional edit

```
require(tidyverse)
require(magrittr)
require(regclass)

#Creating the Sample dataset (I changed the sample to 2500)
set.seed(123)
df <- data.frame(x = sample( LETTERS[1:4], 2500, replace=TRUE, prob=c(0.1, 0.2, 0.69, 0.01)),
                y = sample( LETTERS[6:9], 2500, replace=TRUE, prob=c(0.1, 0.2, 0.68, 0.02)), 
                z = sample(16500:350000, 2500, replace=TRUE))


# Split into 3 parts
set.seed(123)
nums <- c(60, 20, 20)
assignments <- rep(NA, nrow(df))
assignments[sample(nrow(df))] <- rep(c(1, 2, 3), nums)
SplitDF <- split(df, assignments)

#Creating function to filter out factors with less than 10 cases
FilterOut <- function(df) {

  #Creating new factor
  df$NewFactor <- as.factor(
    suggest_levels(z~x,data=df, target=3,recode=TRUE)$newlevels)

  #filter factors with less than 10 cases
  df_filter <- df %>% 
    group_by(NewFactor) %>% 
    mutate(N = n()) %>% 
    filter(N > 10) %>% 
    as.data.frame() %>% 
    #to drop levels without cases
    mutate(NewFactor = factor(NewFactor))

  return(df_filter)
}

#Creating function to get model. I used regression just for the example
ModelFunction <- function(df) {
  Model <- FilterOut(df) %$%
  lm(z ~ NewFactor) %>% 
  broom::tidy()

  return(Model) }

#Filter the three datasets
FilterCases <- lapply(SplitDF, FilterOut)

#Creating the model for the three datasets
SetModel <- lapply(FilterCases, ModelFunction)

SetModel 



$`1`
         term   estimate std.error  statistic   p.value
1 (Intercept) 181708.111  2775.383 65.4713598 0.0000000
2  NewFactorB   8117.848  6286.739  1.2912653 0.1968111
3  NewFactorC  13992.806 27869.233  0.5020879 0.6156795

$`2`
         term    estimate std.error   statistic      p.value
1 (Intercept) 178142.0976  14499.60 12.28600217 1.905931e-30
2  NewFactorB    777.3922  15346.54  0.05065586 9.596203e-01
3  NewFactorC   4435.7520  16926.89  0.26205361 7.933898e-01

$`3`
         term   estimate std.error  statistic      p.value
1 (Intercept) 169001.400  14125.24 11.9644945 3.626713e-29
2  NewFactorB   5949.759  16835.49  0.3534057 7.239342e-01
3  NewFactorC   9378.655  15010.76  0.6247956 5.323920e-01
```

Comment: Thank you ver much for your answer.

Comment: I have realized that while loop is not the best option inr. The thing is I don´t want to loose those levels /groups, but rather reassign them

Comment: The thing is I am going to work on linear regression model and don´t want to loose those levels /groups, but rather reassign them  using suggest_levels function that determines levels that are similar to each other either in terms of their average value of a  variable (in this case z).

Comment: I want to create a function that would take the categorical variable and based on the minimum number of cases whithin the level would return the number of new/reassigned levels whithin the variable using suggest_levels function().  But thank you anyway!

Comment: You're welcome :) I edited my answer due to your comments. Does it solve your problem?

Comment: Hey! If you try and run my while loop code (the one above foo function)

Comment: Hey! If you try and run my while loop code (the one above foo function), then check what is in f. It will give you the number of reassigned levels whithin the variable y given that the minimum number the cases I want is 100 or k. Changing k you will get different f. The while loop actually works.

Comment: I just don´t want to use it 17 times (that´s how many categorical variables I have in my dataset) to get the number of levels which will suit condition of having at least 100 items in each level in each variable. Sorry if it sounds confusing. If you run my while loop you might understand it better)) And thanks again

Comment: I don't really understand what you mean. suggest_levels sets the number of levels that you want, why you need to run in 17 times?. Instead, would you like to explain what is the problem and what you want to code? Try to frame it into points

Comment: Hi there! Ok. 1. I am working on multiple regression model to predict prices of the properties. 2. I have a dataset with around 2500 rows. To train, test and validate my model I devided my dataset in train, test, and validate subsets, 60:20:20 accordingly. 3. whithin some of my categorical variables there are levels that rarely occur. Example: let´s say I have variable neighbourhood which has 10 levels: A-J. Level J only occurs 2 times in all dataset and therefore cannot be found in train, test and validation dataset at the same time.

Comment: So when I train my model on a train dataset where there is no J level and then want to test it it on a test dataset where there is J level it throws an error saying that there is a new level and my model doesn´t recognize it.

Comment: 4. To avoid it I need to have at least 10 Js in my dataset so that they would appear in the three data subsets. So I want to reset the levels with suggest_levels(). function that determines levels that are similar to each other in terms of their average value of the variable Price since that what I want to predict. And I also want to rest them in such way that the minimum number of cases whithin a level would be 10.

Comment: 5. When I use this function manually I would first set the number of levels (target) to 9 (since the number of levels in variable neighbourhood is 10), but it doesn´t neceserily mean that J level will merge with some other level. So than I set it to 8 and so on untill J level merges with some other level.

Comment: 6. That´s why I created the while loop so that when I set the minimum number of cases whithin the level it iterates untill it finds the number of levels that suits the condition.

Comment: 7. Since I have 17 variables with levels that are too low I have to run while loop on each one of them (and therefore 17 times) to identify the number of levels they should have in order to satisfy the condition of having at least 10 cases whithin each level of those variables. To avoid running the loop 17 times I was trying to create a function that would take the categorical variable and return the number of levels to suit the whithin level condition. May be too ambitious.....

Comment: *in 4. "And I also want to rest" -And I also want to set                                    * in 4. "I need to have at least 10 Js in my dataset"  - I ment "I need each level to have at least 10 cases"

Comment: I tried building some basic work flow from what you asked